# How to force login in angular full stack yeoman?

Tags: angularjs, authentication, stack, yeoman

Is there a way to force the user to log in first in an app generated by the angular full stack yeoman ?

I tried to add the following code in the run part of app.js but was not successful

```
Auth.isLoggedIn(function(loggedIn) {
  console.log(loggedIn);
  if (!loggedIn) {
    console.log("redirecting");
    // event.preventDefault();
    $state.go('login');
  }
});
```

I found authentication controls in api index.js files but none for the / landing page ...

Thx

Comment: suggest creating `resolve` in parent state of all states that need login. Child states won;t be accessible if parent won;t resolve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not use google as i should have ! 
To force authentication for a state, just add

`authenticate: true`

in the state (or all states in my case)

Answer (score 1):

Without more code or information on which router you are using (generator-angular-fullstack supports both the default NgRouter and UIRouter) it is tough to give a complete answer. By your answer to your question I am assuming you have UI Router and have figured out how to do client side authentication within the generated fullstack code. However, you will also need to implement something similar to what they have done in their 'users' api to protect your api end points on the server side and return a 401/403 error.

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var controller = require('./user.controller');
var config = require('../../config/environment');
var auth = require('../../auth/auth.service');

var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', auth.hasRole('admin'), controller.index);
router.delete('/:id', auth.hasRole('admin'), controller.destroy);
router.get('/me', auth.isAuthenticated(), controller.me);
router.put('/:id/password', auth.isAuthenticated(),         controller.changePassword);
router.get('/:id', auth.isAuthenticated(), controller.show);
router.post('/', controller.create);

module.exports = router;
```

In the above code (which can be found by navigating to the server folder, then the api folder, then the user folder and looking at index.js) you will see that they are calling a couple of functions.

They are calling auth.hasRole('admin') and auth.isAuthenticated().

Those are functions which can be found in the server side auth/role service under the folder auth and in the auth.service.js file.

```
function hasRole(roleRequired) {
if (!roleRequired) throw new Error('Required role needs to be set');

return compose()
.use(isAuthenticated())
.use(function meetsRequirements(req, res, next) {
  if (config.userRoles.indexOf(req.user.role) >= config.userRoles.indexOf(roleRequired)) {
    next();
  }
  else {
    res.status(403).send('Forbidden');
  }
});
}
```

I think it is important to understand how this is working on the server side also. So, if you navigate to localhost:9000/admin and open console you will see that there is a 401 or 403 error depending on whether or not you are logged in and/or logged in as an admin user.

Comment: Hello Chris. My mistake was to expect a solution from the server side. At the end i only add the following line in each state (so front side)
```
authenticate: true
```
This ensure that you must be authenticated when you try to reach the wanted state.
Not sure what is the best : add this to all states or to the server side in all API

Comment: if you want to protect your api endpoints you should probably add it server side, you can always do both.

Answer (score 0):

Just Paste authenticate:true on main.js

```
angular.module('testcesarApp')
 .config(function ($routeProvider) {
 $routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl',
    authenticate:true
  });
 });
```